# How add vector style rule filter with different value in table

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, style, filter

I have a simple wfs layer from geoserver, here is code:

```
  //wfs-t editable overlay
  var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector sample", {
  strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
  //projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
  protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
  version: "1.1.0",
  // loading data through localhost url path
  url: ".....",
  featureNS :  ".....",
  extractAttributes: true,
  // layer name
  featureType: "....",
  geometryName: "geom",
  schema: "localhost:8080/geoserver......"
  })
  });

 //vector style:
var vector_style = new OpenLayers.Style({ 
'fillColor': '#669933', 
'fillOpacity': .8, 
'strokeColor': '#aaee77', 
'strokeWidth': 3, 
'pointRadius': 8 
});

var vector_style_select = new OpenLayers.Style({ 
'fillColor': '#FF0000', 
'fillOpacity': .10,
'graphicName': 'circle', 
//'label': 'klik',
'pointRadius': 8, 
'strokeColor': '#f86633', 
'strokeDashstyle': 'solid', 
'strokeWidth': 4 
});

var vector_style_iz_table = new OpenLayers.Style({
'cursor': 'pointer', 
'fillColor': '#669933', 
'fillOpacity': .8, 
'fontColor': '#343434', 
'label': '${table1}', 
'pointRadius': '8', 
'strokeColor': '#aaee77',
'strokeWidth': 3, 
'strokeDashstyle': 'solid', 
'strokeWidth': '${4}' 
});
var vector_style_map = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ 
'default': vector_style_iz_table,
'select': vector_style_select 
});
wfs_layer.styleMap = vector_style_map;
```

I have table from "table1" database, where is three different value: "yes", "no" and "null".

Everything works fine, in this style I can view vector layer with green fillcolor with label "yes" or "no" from my "table1".

I want 3 different style, for "yes"-> green fillcolor, for "no"-> red fillcolor and "null"-> black fillcolor.

Is that posible having 3 styles for one vector layer? I think that I must write rule filter for all three different value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a style object with custom rules, with which you can style features depending on their properties. Please have a look at this [page](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html#custom-rules).